# Sinon mocking with Sequelize

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sequelize.js, sinon

I have the following nodejs function using Sequelize:

```
var processDatabase = function (dbConnection, schema, recordsets) {

    var myLogTable = dbConnection.define(schema.tableName, schema.myLogSchema, schema.myLogSchemaIndex);
    myLogTable.sync({

        force: false,
        freezeTableName: true,
        logging: console.log

    }).then(function () {

        console.log('Table synced...');

        for (k = 0; k < recordsets.length; k++) {

            var query = "Some query";

            dbConnection.query(
                    query, {
                        type: dbConnection.QueryTypes.SELECT
                    }
                )
                .then(function (results) {
                    console.log('MYSQL Selection Done');
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    console.log('MYSQL Error: ' + err.message);
                });
        }
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('MYSQL Sync Error: ' + err.message);
    });
};
```

I am new to mocking and do not especially know how to test the catch part.

This is my unit test which I can come up with, but I do not know how a call to sync can go to the catch part:

```
describe('when call processDatabase', function () {

    it('should process successfully when sync fails', function (done) {

        seqConnection.define = function (tableName, schema, schemaIndex) {
            return mockMyLogModel;
        };

        processProfilesNotMapped(seqConnection, {
                        tableName: 'SomeTable',
                        myLogSchema: myLogSchema,
                        myLogSchemaIndex: myLogSchemaIndex
                    }, []);
        done();         
    })
});
```

How would I write my mocking so that I can test both catch and also then so that they can be covered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to defer an exception in your mock, since "sync" is using **promises**. You can use q library or any other. This way when you execute the sync function it will go to the catch section
Example using q:

```
describe('when call processDatabase', function () {

    it('should process successfully when sync fails', function (done) {

        seqConnection.define = function (tableName, schema, schemaIndex) {
            const mock = {
                sync: function(){
                   const deferred = q.defer();
                   deferred.reject(new Error('Some error'));
                   return deferred.promise;
                }
            }
            return mock;
        };

    expect(
        function(){
            cmdManager.execute("getProfileDummy","hosar@gmail.com")
        }
    ).to.throw(Error);

        processProfilesNotMapped(seqConnection, {
                        tableName: 'SomeTable',
                        myLogSchema: myLogSchema,
                        myLogSchemaIndex: myLogSchemaIndex
                    }, []);
        done();         
    })
});
```